# Semantic-ui only worked AFTER editing custom.semantic.json, w/ MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

Steps:

```
meteor create semantic-ui 
cd semantic-ui 
meteor add semantic:ui  
meteor add flemay:less-autoprefixer 
meteor run
```

Update `semantic-ui.html` with this Semantic-ui script:

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>

    <div class="ui three buttons">
      <button class="ui active button">One</button>
      <button class="ui button">Two</button>
      <button class="ui button">Three</button>
    </div>

</template>
```

I DO NOT SEE semantic UI styling.

Create new file `client/lib/custom.semantic.json` don't edit it.

After Meteor server re-starts: Still no semantic UI in browser.

If I edit `custom.semantic.json` i.e. change `"accordion": true,` to:
`"accordion": false,`... now once the meteor server starts I see the Semantic Ui styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a check following your codes, just wonder if you notice

Note: if you are happy with the default values you will need to remove .custom.semantic.json to generate Semantic UI. (see Generating Trigger)

After I rename .custom.semantic.json to custom.semantic.json, it works.